# Confused if I committed kufr

Tags: shirk

I was playing a video game with a friend and he told me to add his account, his account was suspicious to me when I was writing it because I believed his name had a kuffr statement in it, but when I researched his name it turned out it was just Greek meaning for colors, I am terribly afraid that due to me writing his name and having suspicion that his name was Kuffr, that it made me leave the fold of Islam, I know this might sound like a ridiculous question, but I had no intention of leaving Islam or committing kuffr , I just wanted to add my friend on a game